# Email-Headers: Sender vs. x-sender

Tags: email, outlook-2007, email-headers

> If you want to "[Send Email On Behalf
>   Of](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2008/02/26/sending-email-on-behalf-of.aspx)" someone else, should you use
>   the 'Sender' heading or the 'x-sender'
>   heading?

Outlook 2007 seems to *only* pay attention to the 'Sender' heading, if it's present.

On the other hand, there are those who believe that the 'Sender' heading [has been deprecated](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iVVS0OvJ5sUJ:www.stopspam.org/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26id%3D45+x-sender+sender+unusual&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) in favor of the 'x-sender' heading.

Comment: I won't offer an answer without doing actual research, but off the top of my head, I don't believe `Sender` has been deprecated. It's mentioned repeatedly in RFC 2822 (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), so it's not just a UseNet thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use both at the same time. "Sender" and "X-Sender" are not mutually exclusive and neither of them is deprecated.

According to [RFC2822 - Internet Message Format](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) X-headers ought to be nonstandard and provided for information only but in real life this convention does not hold. Using "Sender" and "X-Sender" simultaneously gives you an edge on systems that support only one or the other.